# rails3_acts_as_paranoid and carrierwave: keep images on soft delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, carrierwave, acts-as-paranoid

I am using the two gems [rails3_acts_as_paranoid](https://github.com/goncalossilva/rails3_acts_as_paranoid) and [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave). The soft delete, hard delete and recover functionality of paranoid work fine. However, when I soft delete an item, the stored image is deleted by carrierwave.

How to configure carrierwave or acts_as_paranoid so that the image is deleted only on hard deletes ?

Comment: Same problem here: https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues/624

Answer (score 2):

In the model, add the following line after mount_uploader:

```
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
skip_callback :commit, :after, :remove_image!
```

Note: it won't affect the other commit callbacks. Eg: `after_commit :do_smth` would still work.

You can call `@model_instance.remove_image!` if you want to get rid of the image when doing a hard delete